# Json get item from array in an array C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I have the following class for my Json data I receive:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class OrderInfoResult
{
    [JsonProperty("ok")]
    public Boolean OK { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("menu")]
    public List<Menu> Menu { get; set; }
}
public class Menu
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("icon-url")]
    public string IconUrl { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("items")]
    public List<Menu> Items { get; set; }
}
public class Items
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("icon-url")]
    public string IconUrl { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("price")]
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

I try to get the items inside the Menu, so far I could reach lets say Name of a Menu without a problem by using a foreach loop, but when I do a foreach inside a foreach I can't reach the Item itself.

I have to following loop:

```
foreach (var desoi in deserializedOrderInfo.Menu)
{
  foreach (var desoiItem in desoi.Items)
  {
    var clickableBoxv = new RoundedBackgroundBoxView
    {
      CornerRadius = 6,
      Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 5),
      Index = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(desoiItem.Id),
      Name = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(desoiItem.Name),
      Price = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(desoiItem.Price),
    };
  }
}
```

Using this I get the error that there is no "Price" in Menu, while I thought that "desoiItem" would be the Items list, not the Menu List.

How can I use the info inside the Items Class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the feeling this is supposed to say `List<Items>` instead:

```
public List<Menu> Items { get; set; }
```

(And I would rename the class to `MenuItem` or something, having a plural class name such as `Items` for a single item is weird)

Comment: Oh wow, Thanks! So that was why. totally didn't see that one. Will accept this as answer when possible!

Comment: Free ProTip: `var` can mask errors sometimes. You could use the actual type instead of `var` when it's not obvious like here, or at least just hover over the `var` in VS which shows you the actual type as a tooltip.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that (: